# DataTables Add Row missing data

Tags: datatables, rows, missing-data

When I run the following code with varying amounts of data, only a subset of the rows are added.

In the following example, the createdRow callback is always called the same amount of times as elements in the array of rows (ie. 5 out of 5). However, the rowCallback callback is only called a subset of those times(ie. 3 out of 5). I'll pass 5 rows and 3 will be added or 13 rows and 8 will be added. I can't figure out a pattern to it.

I've upgraded dataTables to the most recent version (1.10.9). I've tried adding the rows one at a time in a loop.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
sub_table = $('#data-table-check-off').DataTable({
    "dom": 'ft',
    "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "", "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search" },
    "sScrollY": "250px",
    "stateSave": true,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "paging": false,
    "rowCallback": function(row, data, index) {
        console.log("in rowCallback");
    },
    "createdRow": function(row, data, index) {
       console.log("in createdRow");
    }
});

var rows = [["12","Lorenzo"],["14", "Holly"],["15", "Chad"],["16", "Bear"],["17", "Zack"]];
sub_table.rows.add(rows).draw(false);
```

Comment: I get equal number of calls for 5 records, see https://jsfiddle.net/5nxg1e6j/

Comment: Update: Upon further testing, I found this only happens on one of my pages. All pages that access this table are importing the same JS and HTML for the table. Something outside of the datatable must be effecting it somehow since its calling the same code? Not sure what yet... still troubleshooting.

Comment: Is there anything different about that page? DataTables initialization options?

Comment: This ended up being caused by a filter on a different table that was being applied to this table. Since you can't apply filters to only one data table within a page, I added some more logic to my filter to ignore one of the tables. Thanks for the help!